# OCTAVE printing plots

Tags: octave

I've just started using OCTAVE and am facing an issue with the print command for plots. I tried using for a very basic plot:

```
plot([0 1],[0 1]);
print(1,"-deps","test","-S576,432");
```

And it drops the error:

> GL2PS warning: Unknown token in buffer

and just freezes indefinitely.

I'm using the latest version of OCTAVE for windows which is 8.3.0 and my OS is Windows 11 Pro 22H2

If I try to stop it by using Ctrl+C it drops the error:

> ```
> Error: /undefinedfilename in (C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\oct-HqAbSk)
> Operand stack:
>
> Execution stack:
>    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
> Dictionary stack:
>    --dict:732/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--
> Current allocation mode is local
> Last OS error: No such file or directory
> GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
> ```

Comment: You should always look at the [documentation](https://docs.octave.org/v4.4.0/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html): You are using the form `print (h, filename, options)`. The second argument is `"-deps"`, which is taken as `filename`, and then `"test"` is taken as the first of the options. Try reversing those two arguments.

Comment: I tried doing that, but it still gives me the same error.